# How to get a horizontal scrollbar to show when scrolling in a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've enabled

```
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
```

In my TextView - and it can scroll horizontally and vertically. However, only the vertical scorllbar shows and never the horizontal one. How can I get it to show?

This textview is in a ScollView as well (so I can have elements that are non-scrolling). The textviews width and height are both wrap_content, scrollviews are both match_parent.

Comment: what do you have height and width set to?

Comment: Have you set your TextView width to FILL_PARENT?

Comment: Tried, no effect. I've updated my question with the relevant information.